# How to export Group module entities with the Features module?

Tags: 7, features, group

I'm trying to find a way in D7 to export groups created with the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module using the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module. I have managed to export Group Types and Group Roles, but haven't found a way of doing the same with Groups.

I need to do this to create an initial set of groups when the feature is enabled.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [UUID Features Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features) module, which provides a mechanism for exporting content (nodes, taxonomy, fields) into a features module. It depends on the [UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) and [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module. Some more info aboout this module(from its [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2261719)):

> Drupal's core entities are supported by default within the UUID module, but if you want to export content contained within ***custom entities***, you will have to implement UUID support using their API.

The challenge with the [UUID Features Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features) module is that its documentation is not complete (yet). So for adding UUID Features support for custom content entities (such as ***Groups***), refer to the module's [includes/](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/uuid_features/tree/includes) folder and use one of the existing implementations as an example.

2 more documentation issues that may be of some help also:

- Issue [# 2310115](https://www.drupal.org/node/2310115).
- Issue [# 2236497](https://www.drupal.org/node/2236497).